Trying to make a python exe that works on all computers
Ive been trying to turn my pthon script into a standalone exe with pyinstaller, the problem is I need to include python-vlc and when I run
pyinstaller --add-binary "E:\Documents\Spotify Posters\Spotify Poster Coding Shit\libvlc.dll;." --add-binary "E:\Documents\Spotify Posters\Spotify Poster Coding Shit\libvlccore.dll;." --onefile test3.py

I get the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test3.py", line 1120, in <module>
        main()
    File "test3.py", line 1116, in main
        app = SpotifyPosterApp(root)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "test3.py", line 108, in ~init~
        self.backgroundplayer = vlc.MediaPlayer(BACKGROUNDVIDEO_PATH) 
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "vlc.py", line 3287, in __new
        AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'media_player_new'
[32308] Failed to execute script 'test3' due to unhandled exception!

if I dont include the binaries the code will run as an exe on my main PC but I need it so that the code can be transferred to multiple PCs and the moment I include the binaries I get the error stated above, any help would be great thank you

Please format your error so it's readable by the audience here.

if using windows, the full path might need "\" or "/" .  A single backslash is an escape character.

I'm pretty sure that the --add-data and --add-binary take the format SOURCE:DEST meaning that the separator is a colon (:), not a semi-colon (;). Try a relative path instead.
e.g. say you run the installer from the folder Spotify Posters
pyinstaller --add-binary "Spotify Poster Coding Shit\libvlc.dll:." --add-binary "Spotify Poster Coding Shit\libvlccore.dll:." --onefile test3.py


